# Migrate from a xcode codification to phonegap codification

Tags: xcode, cordova, interface, migrate

I made originally an application in Xcode and I finished but I want to add more functionality, but now I want to use PhoneGap but reuse my interface that I had on the first version but this its made on Xcode directly, and now I will use Dreamweaver, is this possible?

Comment: You will have to create your UI from scratch using HMTL...

Comment: I was afraid of that but I was wondering if there was something else thank you